Contrasts by each categorical factor or by all?
I have the following model:
Cmic_mg_cm2 ~ group*sample_date + mean_ph + mean_shan_veg + 
              mean_tree_shandiv + (1|plot)

with both group and sample_date being both categorical factor variables
I am using it to examine the following questions:
Is there a difference between groups for a given sample date?
Is there a difference between sample dates for a given group?
Do any of the covariates have an effect?
This model is purely intended for inferral and not for predictions - random effect is included to deal with pseudo replication of sampling.
When examining contrasts with the R emmeans package one has the option to examine all pairings, only the "group" pairs and only the "sample_date" pairs. My question is, which is more valid as of course combining all pairs leads to more multiple testing and thus higher penalisation when p.adjusting for this.

Which contrasts you want to look at is directly related to which questions you want to ask. It seems like you are interested in several things.
